# turn on push notifications drive google

Tags: push-notification, google-api, drive

I am attempting to set up push notifications for a file in my drive (its a sheet, is that the problem?) -- i am following this example (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) and I just want to turn the watching ON.... the example just says "auth_token_for_current_user" and I can't seem to get an access token to make this POST example work to save my life. I used the https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ and got an access token but it was continuously refused. My domain is valid and registered, I feel sure I have selected the correct scopes.... what can I be doing wrong? My sample json, id/domain changed to protect the innocent:

headers, "Application-Type:": "content/json"
auth_token: "the one that playground provided"

{
  "id": "0a8b18c2-ef85-11e6-8d22...", 
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "http://my-domain/notifications"
}

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I believe the issue for you is that the **google oauth playground does not recognize which domains you have authorized.**

You need to programmatically generate the access token. Please follow this link, to see the steps to take for Node. [Nodejs drive api quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) There are other quickstart guides for python and such as well.

If you follow this quickstart tutorial, it will make a folder in your home directory called .credentials

Then it will generate a file inside of this folder called  'drive-nodejs-quickstart.json' by default. Once this file is generated, look inside and grab out the access token. Use this in your POST request and your push notifications will work.